# Is there any way to read fetch emails from mail server in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, imap, mail-server, codeigniter-email

I'm trying to read emails in codeigniter. So far I've learned that imap is used to read email but when I use imap there comes an error which says `Call to undefined function imap_open()`.

I'm using using following function to connect to mail server.

```
$imap = imap_open($mailboxPath, $username, $password);
```

I'm stuck now and couldn't find any point to start with. How can I proceed?